# How to fix a Kafka error "IOException caught when establishing connection to https://stream.twitter.com" in Java?

Tags: java, twitter, apache-kafka, connection, ioexception

Using Kafka, I am trying to stream data from twitter into Java, but when I run the program I am getting this error:

```
[hosebird-client-io-thread-0] WARN com.twitter.hbc.httpclient.ClientBase - Hosebird-Client-01 IOException caught when establishing connection to https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/filter.json?delimited=length&stall_warnings=true
[hosebird-client-io-thread-0] WARN com.twitter.hbc.httpclient.ClientBase - Hosebird-Client-01 failed to establish connection properly
[hosebird-client-io-thread-0] INFO com.twitter.hbc.httpclient.ClientBase - Hosebird-Client-01 Done processing, preparing to close connection
```

1. I am trying to receive streams for a particular hashtag element.  I checked the dependency in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.twitter</groupId>
  <artifactId>hbc-core</artifactId> 
  <version>2.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

2. Running the curl command, I get this message:

```
$ curl -I https://stream.twitter.com
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
content-length: 0
date: Wed, 26 Jun 2019 13:28:19 GMT
server: tsa_a
set-cookie: personalization_id="v1_HSs6Yj5MLa8Ct13KsRWj3A=="; Max-Age=63072000; Expires=Fri, 25 Jun 2021 13:28:19 GMT; Path=/; Domain=.twitter.com
set-cookie: guest_id=v1%3A156155569958747022; Max-Age=63072000; Expires=Fri, 25 Jun 2021 13:28:19 GMT; Path=/; Domain=.twitter.com
strict-transport-security: max-age=631138519
x-connection-hash: 567cd8537e0e96252c2175e59d752883
x-response-time: 2
```

3. and tried regenerating the keys and tokens.

Here's a snippet of the code:

```
public void run(){

// Setting blocking queues
BlockingQueue<String> msgQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<String>(1000);

// create a twitter client
Client client = createTwitterClient(msgQueue);

// Establish a connection.
client.connect();

// looping thru code
// etc
}
```

```
public Client createTwitterClient(BlockingQueue<String> msgQueue){

// Declared the keys and tokens

// Host to connect to, the endpoint, and authentication (basic auth or oauth) */

Hosts hosebirdHosts = new HttpHosts(Constants.STREAM_HOST); <- this guy
StatusesFilterEndpoint hosebirdEndpoint = new StatusesFilterEndpoint();

// rest of the code for ClientBuilder and Client
}
```

Where Constants.STREAM_HOST is:

```
public static final String STREAM_HOST = "https://stream.twitter.com";
```

I expect the connection gets established and be able to receive tweets.  What would be the cause that the STREAM_HOST is not establishing a connection?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for those who even read my questions.

It seems this is happening due to my laptop firewall settings.  I tried the exact same code with another less-secure laptop and it works like a charm.  Will need to figure out with an admin.

Comment: I was facing same issue , your comment resolved my issue .

Comment: I had an Symantec WSS agent working in the backend. Once I disable that I was able to receive tweets.